# Play music from spotify library in my own java application

Tags: java, spotify

Im developing a home control system that i can use in my home. I've figured how to control lights, AC/Heat and alarm with a java application that i made. But there is one thing that i cant figure out how to do. I want to play music from spotify on my speakers, with this java application that i made. I've figured out how to play music from a library on my server, but i can't find a example on how to get acces to the spotify library with java. Is it possible at all? If so, how can i do it?

Comment: There is a wrapper for the C spotify API for Java here. https://code.google.com/p/jlibspotify/

Comment: Maybe you should have a look with iframes possibilities.

Comment: The Java wrapper looks like a good solution, thank you arynaq :)